# When executing Composer commands error "'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: php, laravel, path, composer-php

So I've been trying to install Laravel with Composer for about a week and a half now using windows 10 and wamp and even Homestead at one point. Every time I execute the "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel demo" or anything else that Composer uses PHP to be executed, the error " 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" appears.

When searching for this problem all solutions point to the Path variable and adding a PHP path to it, but that's not the problem. Executing PHP commands normally without Composer works 100% of the time with 0 errors and the PHP path already exists. Only when using Composer does this error appear.

Can someone please help me find out how to solve this problem? It's an emergency. I'm about to graduate college and I need to use Laravel to make my end of Semester project. I'd gladly share any information to those who want to help me solve this problem.

Comment: This might help... [Append '@'](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4126)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add C:\xampp\php to your PATH environment variable.
Then close your command prompt and restart again.

Then Install Composer using the Command-line

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer- setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Test the install

```
php composer.phar
```

Answer (score 1):

I got that same error. I fixed  my error using in this way. Adding our PHP.exe's folder to our System PATH variables, so PHP can be accessed via terminal.

Ex . `C:\xampp\php\`

We need to add `PATH` variable.

[image]

1. Right click on MyPC , select **Properties**
2. Select `Advanced System` Settings.
3. System Properties window click the `Environment Variables` button.
4. Select `System Variables` -> `Path` and click Edit.
5. Add the folder where your `C:\xampp\php is located.
6. If you did this correctly, restart your terminal and type `php --version` to check if it works.

Comment: I try this method Its good

Answer (score 0):

Since Wampserver complains loudly when you add PHP to the `PATH` variable I tried to find an alternate solution.

I installed Composer globally as an "executable" on my Windows machine. It got installed in `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`. The install consists of the `composer.phar` file and a `composer.bat`.

By editing the .bat file I was able to add the path to PHP (in my case `c:\php\`) for composer, without adding it to the `PATH` environment variable:

```
c:\php\php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```